# Import Error: "TransformGraphWithStringInputs" from tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu

I am trying to import "TransformGraphWithStringInputs' on multiple tensorflow versions (2.10/.3/.13) and python versions 3.8/3.10 and something seems to cause the following error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'TransformGraphWithStringInputs' from 'tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow' (/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py)

Any ideas on why that might be the case?

Comment: It's probably not there. `from tensorflow.python.util._pywrap_transform_graph import TransformGraphWithStringInputs`

Comment: Thing is it should according to the official repository from TF. I checked gitk for it and it seems to be valid for all the 2. versions.